# Authorization in Azure AD B2C for the react React Native app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, react-native, azure-ad-b2c

### Does anyone succeed in **creating react native app with authorization in Azure Ad B2C?**

I did it for the React web app and .Net Core API but, any library which I found for React Native does not work right know and I'm beginner in React Native. Please give me some hints tutorials or repos. I got stuck so bad.

Answer (score 0):

I found an working React-Native library for Azure AD B2C. You can follow [this article](https://sonyarouje.com/2019/02/07/react-native-library-for-azure-ad-b2c/).
Here is the example:

```
import B2CAuthentication from "../auth-ad-js/ReactNativeADB2C";
import LoginView from "../auth-ad-js/LoginView";

const CLIENT_ID = "<provide your client id>";

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Login"
  };

  render() {
    const b2cLogin = new B2CAuthentication({
      tenant: 'yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com',
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: "<key set in application/key>",
      user_flow_policy: "B2C_1_signupsignin",
      reset_password_policy: 'B2C_1_password_reset',
      token_uri: "https://saroujetmp.b2clogin.com/saroujetmp.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token",
      authority_host: "https://saroujetmp.b2clogin.com/saroujetmp.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
      redirect_uri: "https://functionapp120190131041619.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback",
      prompt: "login",
      scope: ["https://saroujetmp.onmicrosoft.com/api/offline_access", "offline_access"]
    });

    return (
      <LoginView
        context={b2cLogin}
        onSuccess={this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
  onLoginSuccess(credentials) {
    console.log("onLoginSuccess");
    console.log(credentials);
    // use credentials.access_token..
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I also found that but probably do something wrong with this. Can you describe steps which you did to achieve this ?

Comment: My case is really easy, I don't use azure function. I just looking for easy way of oauth using ADB2C in react native

Comment: there is no discription in the repo you mentioned, how to use it ?